# Why an additional random number (which is not used) would cause the simulation results changed?

Tags: r, simulation

#the following codes simulate the size of the F-test (alpha=0.1)

```
set.seed(123) 
n=4;p=1;q=1;
nu1=p; nu2=n-p-q+1;;
alpha=0.1

critical=qf(alpha,nu1,nu2,lower.tail=FALSE ) 

rep=100000
i=1
# M<- rf(rep, q, n-q+1);
rej=0 
while (i<=rep){ 
  rL=  rf(1,nu1 , nu2);
  if (rL >=critical) {rej=rej+1;} 
  i=i+1;   
} 
r=rej/rep
```

---

The result is accurate: 0.0993. |Error|<0.0008.

However, if the "#"-sign is removed from the above codes, the results is bad (0.09859). |Error|>0.0013.
If alpha=0.38, then the |error| can be >0.002. I tried to increase the number of simulation from 100,000 to 1,000,000, but still has |error|>0.001.
Any reason?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMfrT.png)

I tried to insert another random value, but the simulation result is bad. It cannot be improved thru the increase of replicates and the |ERROR| is always>0.001.

Comment: it's usually a good idea to add a tag for the language or app you are using, because Stack Overflow has questions about code in dozens of languages.  Also, FYI with random number generators making additional calls will always change the results because it will shift which values go to which variables.  if the sequence was 1,2,3,4,5 and extra code consumes the 3 then the other code now uses 1,2, 4,5  not 1,2,3,4

Comment: This looks to be R, from what little I know of it.

Answer (score 3):

Most random generators aren’t random. They’re [psuedorandom](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) state machines  give the same deterministic sequence of results given same seed.

Drawing a random number out (regardless of whether you end up using it or not) advances this sequence, giving you different numbers as input to your simulation.

Comment: This is a better answer than my incomplete comment above, above since there do exist other random number generators that use things like CPU hardware noise  that are nondeterministic.  In this case we have `set.seed(123)` so it looks like a pseudorandom sequence with a fixed seed that should only change when additional RNG calls are added or removed from the code.

Answer (score 1):

As @Alexander says, drawing another random number changes your position in the random-number stream, changing all of the downstream results. In general, though, if you're doing something numerically stable/with low variance, there might not be much difference.

Some slightly more efficient code to run the same simulation *many* times: you'll see that the size of the test is greater than the nominal level about half the time, less about half the time (and in fact the distribution of sizes matches an appropriately scaled binomial distribution ...)

```r
sizefun <- function(nsim = 10000, n= 4, p = 1, q = 1, alpha = 0.1) {
    nu1=p; nu2=n-p-q+1
    crit <- qf(alpha, nu1, nu2, lower.tail = FALSE)
    M <- rf(nsim, nu1, nu2)
    mean(M>=crit)
}
set.seed(123) 
results <- replicate(1000, sizefun())
h1 <- hist(results, freq = FALSE)
nsim <- 10000
## tweak binomial distribution to make curve match density of results
curve(dbinom(round(x*nsim), prob = 0.1, size = nsim)*nsim,
    add = TRUE, col = 2)
```

[image]

We could also make a Gaussian approximation to the binomial (which would be very accurate since `n` is large), and compute the probability that the computed size was in (1-eps, 1+eps) ....